# How to do an Authorize + Capture flow for Google Pay with Paypal?

Tags: javascript, paypal, payment-gateway, google-pay

I'm integrating Google Pay in a simple E-Commerce website. We're using Adyen as the payment gateway.

Everything is working fine if I just pass it an amount, tap "Pay" and the payment is complete.

Now here's the issue: We also need the user's shipping address to calculate the shipping costs. With the simple "just capture" flow we sure get that data, but *after* the payment was complete. Also, we have to present a summary page before we capture the payment.

So:
We need an Authorize + Payment flow, where we get the shipping address after the authorization. Then we calculate the shipping costs and and adjust the actual amount in the capture request later on.

Fair enough. But: **I'm using Paypal as a payment method for Google Pay**. My understanding is that it generates some kind of a virtual Credit Card so it can be used as one. This is my only option since I don't have a real credit card.

Now, this works great for the "just capture" flow, but as soon as we introduce an Authorization step, it looks like I'm being forced to log into Google and to enter a real Credit Card.

Google provides [a way to test with fake Card numbers](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/test-card-suite), but when I turn them on I can't request the shipping address anymore (error OR-ACC-01).

So here is my question:
**Is it possible to achieve an Authorize + Capture checkout flow with Google Pay when the only payment method connected to Google Pay is Paypal?**

Here is a setup with an Authorization step and a required email address and shipping address:

https://jsfiddle.net/0n8tbeu3/2/

with the relevant part being:

```
paymentDataRequest.callbackIntents = ["PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION"];
paymentDataRequest.shippingAddressRequired = true;
paymentDataRequest.emailRequired = true;
```

I expect it to work with my GPay, but instead I'm forced to enter a new / real Credit Card.

### **EDIT:**

To clear things up, here are some screenshots.

### **1.** No `AUTHORIZATION` or `SHIPPING_METHOD` intent.

`// paymentDataRequest.callbackIntents = ["PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION"];`

**On Mobile**: I get the default GPay payment sheet and can complete the payment. (sorry for bad quality, had to take it with my poor webcam since that screen is protected):[image]

**On Desktop**:
I can't complete the payment unless I enter a credit card. Paypal is shown as "not available here" (the credit card input form is collapsed and I've reused the screenshot from an attempt *with* the Authorization intent because the relevant part is exactly the same)

[image]

### **2.** WITH `AUTHORIZATION` and `SHIPPING_METHOD` intent (the callbacks are of course configured as well).

`paymentDataRequest.callbackIntents = ["PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION", "SHIPPING_METHOD"];`

I get basically the same screen as above on Mobile and Desktop where it says that Paypal is not available and prompts me for a credit card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to make sure I understand what you are trying to achieve in case it can be solved in another way.

Are you ultimately after the shipping address to calculate shipping costs? And you want to be able to explicitly authorize the payment before performing the capture. Or are you doing the authorize so that you can receive the shipping address?

I suggest calculating the shipping costs using [dynamic price update](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos#dynamic-price-update-example). The relevant parts are:

- `callbackIntents = ["SHIPPING_ADDRESS",  "SHIPPING_OPTION", ...];`, and
- `paymentDataCallbacks: { onPaymentDataChanged }`

To handle authorization, use the `PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION` callback as well:

- `callbackIntents = [..., "PAYMENT_AUTHORIZATION"];`, and
- `paymentDataCallbacks: { onPaymentAuthorized }`

> as soon as we introduce an Authorization step, it looks like I'm being forced to log into Google and to enter a real Credit Card.

I'm not sure what the deal is here. Are you able to provide some screenshots or a screen recording?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time! We do actually need to be able to trigger the Capture manually becuase we have to let the user review their data befor making the actual payment. So the Authorize step ist not only for the sake of the shipping address. I did see the `SHIPPING_ADDRESS` and `SHIPPING_OPTION` intents, but I'm not sure how to pass the calculatet shipping costs back to Google? My understanding is that I can pass some shipping options on the inital request, but I need at least the shipping country to know which options are available and how much they cost.

Comment: `Are you able to provide some screenshots or a screen recording?` Unfortunately not without doxxing myself. But it's actually quite simple: If I try to directly capture a payment, I'm presented with the standard payment sheet where I can tap on Pay and complete the payment. But if I add an Authorization intent, instead of the payment sheet I'm being asked to enter a real credit card. Paypal is grayed out with a note that it's not available here. I guess it's really hard to reproduce though because most people probably do use real credit cards with their Google Pay

Comment: There's an example on how to calculate shipping costs: https://jsfiddle.net/ynt8p152/. The heavy lifting is done in the `onPaymentDataChanged` method.

Comment: Dude... I'm feeling so stupid right now! It literally says in the docs that `onPaymentDataChanged` has to return a Promise which is then being picked up again by the GPay handler. Thank you so much, that example really clicked for me. That Paypal issue still remains though, but I guess that's just how it works - you only can authorize real credit cards. Will try to get more info on that. But one annoying issue is now solved thanks to you!

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not sure what the problem is with PayPay. I didn't have the same problem you did with the JSFiddle you provided. Having some redacted screenshots might help me understand better. By the way, if you're doing a web integration, there are some web [framework specific libraries](https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button) (React, Angular and web components) available that should make integration easier.

Comment: So just to make it perfectly clear: You only have Paypal connected to your GPay and nothing else, and still the `AUTHORIZATION` and `SHIPPING_ADDRESS` intents just work for you? Maybe I should really just try one of the libraries. I haven't yet because, you know, how hard can it be to pass some stupid params to an API for an awesom dev like me... Thanks again for bearing with me and letting me pick your brain. I *really* appreciate it! This has driving me nuts for days now! Will try do get some screenshots if it still fails. Please let me know if I can buy you a coffee somehow :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, just letting you know that I've added some screenshots to my question in case it somehow helps. It's all in German though, but I think the UI is quite self explanatory. Couldn't get the examples working (the Vue one won't compile for me), but the example fiddle (jsfiddle.net/ynt8p152) should be just as good, so I tested it with that.

Comment: Okay, so I was able to reproduce by changing my Google Pay country to Germany and only having a PayPal account. Ideally you would be using the test cards solution that you mentioned in your original post, however, as you noted it doesn't work with shipping address which sounds like the root cause of your problem. I will pass this feedback onto the team.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I really hope this gets fixed soon. As for the test cards: As soon as I join the user group "Google Pay API Test Cards Allowlist", I can't request any payments with a shipping address at all and all I get is the payment sheet with an error that says *"Ein unerwarteter Fehler ist aufgetreten. Bitte versuchen Sie es später erneut. [OR-ACC-01]"* - so basically "unexpected error, try again later". When I leave the group, all is back to normal again. Regardless, thanks a ton for your efforts!

Comment: FYI, the issue related to `OR-ACC-01` should now be resolved.